# One Stored Procedure to insert one table and retrieve ID and insert multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables and columns. ex: Green (userID, Name, Address), Red (userID, TemproraryAddress), Blue (userID, WorkPlace).

I want to insert data into Green while userID is auto incremented int and unique id. After inserting those details want to retrieve userID and insert into Red and Blue Tables in one stored procedure

Note: This example table is to show a sample scenario, not for real world usage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @userID INT;
INSERT dbo.Green(Name, Address) SELECT @name, @address;
SELECT @userID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT dbo.Red(UserID, TemporaryAddress) SELECT @userID, @something;
INSERT dbo.Blue(UserID, WorkPlace) SELECT @userID, @something_else;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a very nice OUTPUT feature.

In this scenario, specify your identity column with an auto incrementing int or default value (such as newid()), do the insert and then use the output as input for your other input queries.

The output table has all the values just inserted and can be queried just as any other table, with the difference being it has your new value immediately available after commit.

```
INSERT INTO 
tblInsertedID(ID) 
SELECT * FROM
    (INSERT 
    INTO tblDir(Dir) 
    OUTPUT inserted.ID 
    VALUES ('C:\NewDir\')
    ) InnerTable
```

Comment: How do you use `OUTPUT` to subsequently insert into two different tables? You can't, you'd need to stuff the output into a table variable or, if the original insert is just a single row, just use SCOPE_IDENTITY() and a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to insert value in a variable for user is and then use this variable value in Red/Blue tables.